# Spring Data JPA how to pass a variable by using @repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

Thank U, guys! I have found the solution:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>{       
    @Query(value = "select * from Book where find_in_set(:market,market)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Book> findBooksByMarcket(@Param("market") String market);
}
```

**Original question**

I'm using the @Query annotation to create queries by using the JPA query language and to bind these queries directly to the methods of my repository interface.

My database is created correctly and I'm successful to create some queries except this one:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>{       
    @Query("select b from Book b where find_in_set(:market,b.market)")
    public List<Book> findBooksByMarcket(@Param("market") String market);
}
```

I can get the correct result by using the find_in_set function when I check it though MySql. But I cannot reach to pass a variable in java. I have searched though the internet but I cannot find the correct format for it.

please help and thank you guys!

Comment: There is no such thing as find_in_set in JPQL. JPQL and SQL are two different languages.

Comment: Why can't you use like or = by the way? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: If any of bellow answers solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to transform the JPQL query to a native query (by setting the `nativeQuery` flag to true):

```
@Query(value = "select * from Book b where find_in_set(:market,b.market)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Book> findBooksByMarcket(@Param("market") String market);
```

Comment: It comes another issue: Syntax error on token ""select b from Book b where find_in_set(:market,b.market)"", invalid MemberValuePairs...

Comment: I think you lacked a "value"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom MySQL function and want to utilize it in a JPA repository, please take a look at [tip 1](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/)
There is another way to do it using CriteriaBuilder (I used this mechanism along with JPA specification): [tip 2](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-call-custom-function-criteriaquery/)
Key words for your search: custom db function, JPA specification, CriteriaBuilder, Criteria

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>{       
    @Query("select b from Book b where find_in_set(?1,b.market)")
    public List<Book> findBooksByMarcket(String market);
}
```

Comment: Any exception is coming